# Compact way to generate a square wave with double pulse (like a heartbeat)?

Tags: oscillator, 555, multivibrator

I'd like to drive [a small vibrating motor](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1201) to produce a heartbeat-like effect by feeding it a square wave such as the one below.

[image]

Times `t1` and `t2` will be on the order of ¼ second. I'd like time `tb` to be user-variable *eg* by a potentiometer on a dial.

I can see how to generate this by ANDing together two 555s (or halves of a 556) of different frequencies, but that requires a bunch of additional components - 4 RC networks, diodes, a FET to AND the signals together, etc. But I'm trying to fit this all into a 4sq.in. space and along with the battery and switches that might be a tight squeeze.

Is there a more physically compact way to achieve the same effect?

This is for a one-off piece made by hand, not mass-manufacture.

Comment: LOts of small.cheap micros out there just begging to do this.

Comment: @Trevor Any suggestions in particular? I'm inexperienced in the physical electronics space so don't even know the right words to search on (unless you're suggesting something like a PIC which seems overkill).

Comment: Yes a small pic would work great.

Comment: The spectral response or QRST of a heartbeat does not match your waveform. But this can be done easily with a narrow pulse and matched spectral LPF. Then the pulse repetition pattern can be easily done with one shots.

Comment: You may also want to experiment with a Piezo element instead of that motor too. You little cell batteries will not last long driving a motor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your 4 sq. inches is shaped like, but an Arduino Nano is 0.75" x 1.75".

[image: Nano]

They're cheap as chips, especially if you get a Chinese knock off.  Just a couple/ three pounds.  It can run of a variety of voltages, 5 - 12V, so a 9V battery might fit.  You only mentioned area and not volume, so you might be able to stack this stuff.

The business case for the Nano is that it can do everything you want, including reading a potentiometer via inbuilt analogue to digital converters.  They run fast enough for what you want. It can be reprogrammed in situ if you change your mind, and most importantly there are zillions of users out there.  I don't know what you're going to use it for, but I suspect that someone out there has already done it and posted their code on line.  It also reduces your chip count to 1 + FET.  Your motor spec. acutally suggests running it directly from an Arduino so you might be able to loose the FET.  I guess this depends on how much vibration you need.  And it's standard thru the hole mounted.  Not of that space age surface mount stuff which is beginner /breadboard friendly.

There is also arduino.stackexchange who will be able to help you with every step.  There are many other sites too.

I would recommend against a PIC.  Compared to the entire Arduino universe, they're very complex, hugely expensive for the toolset and you will find support difficult as the huge variety of PICs fragments the user base.  Your use case can be programmed in Arduino language (C and Java like) probably in no more than 10 - 15 lines of code.

Please do not fall into the trap of thinking that a micro controller is overkill.  It might be strictly in terms of technical functionality, but in the round, it's the easiest and least risky approach to this.

Comment: The space is ellipsoidal and about 8mm deep. I didn't realize that Nanos had gotten so cheap - last time I used an Arduino they were > $20 apiece and quite bulky.

I possess none of the toolchain necessary for programming PICs so something that can be programmed over a USB port sounds much better.  My biggest worry with a microcontroller is power draw - this whole thing needs to be run off button batteries unless I can find a rechargable that fits.

The project is a bit of costume jewelry - a locket that thumps like a heart when held in hand.

Comment: @Crashworks The 8mm /button cell restrictions would have been useful a bit earlier :-)    However, if you chop those 6 vertical header pins off, you might make it.  Also, Nano's have a sleep function that allow them to sleep.  I think sleepy current might be able to go as low as 10uA if you see https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/reducing-arduino-power-consumption.  How will loved one tell the locket that it's being held?  If it's something like a tilt switch, it could totally power off the locket when hanging vertically drawing naught.

Comment: If you want an even cheaper platform, at the cost of slightly less community support, the STM32F103C8T6 boards floating around on your Chinese retailer of choice are typ. <2USD.

Comment: @PaulUszak Probably I would just use a mechanical switch. The locket is shaped like an anatomical heart so the general intention is to startle unsuspecting children.

It seems coin cells can't supply enough current for a motor in any case so either I need to find a way to squeeze a AAAA in there (or conduct power through the case), or find a piezo component instead.

Comment: @PaulUszak Also for future reference - after your suggestion I went searching for tiny Arduini and found this especially tiny one: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1501

Comment: If you want to use deep sleep states the Arduino Nano is non-ideal. It's advantage is that the serial/USB stuff is built on the board but you cannot turn it off (low power). A better choice for low power is the Arduino Pro mini ...about $2 but needs an external USB/serial adapter to program it.  The Trinket uses an ATTiny85 and is quite non-standard. Another similar ATTiny85 option is the Digispark (from Ebay).

Answer (score 1):

A simple MCU, sot or 8 pin, will do it.

Or a logic gate: counting two pulses and then disable the output for a period of time....

Can be done with 555 too.